# Internet Protocol Port vs TCP Port vs UDP Port

Tags: tcp, udp, portforwarding

I'm trying to set up some port forwarding to enable a device which lies inside my private home network. It requires a number of ports to be forwarded and a number of guides I have read regarding setting this up says to set port x TCP to forward, port y UDP to forward, and occasionally uses the phrase "Internet Protocol Port" z. What is Internet Protocol ports vs UDP/TCP? Does that mean both UDP and TCP? I've never seen something that forwards IP ports; only TCP/UDP.

I am familiar with TCP and UDP, just not the term "Internet Protocol Port". Where would I port forward an IP port in DD-WRT if not using TCP/UDP?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "Internet Protocol port". There are TCP and UDP and SCTP ports.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here is a reference from Microsoft that makes use of the term: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233256

Answer (score -1):

I see now that I mixed up the terms in my head after reading through the guides. It was Internet Protocol "ID", not "port". That term refers to a pool of protocols of which UDP and TCP are examples. When that guide says to enable Internet Protocol ID it is asking to enable Authentication Header which I gathered is a protocol in itself at the level of UDP or TCP.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers

Comment: No, the authentication header is part of IPSec.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the clarification. Just referencing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers explanation of it. That makes sense, though.